# In Python, change the attributes of a class instance which is passed as input to __init__

Tags: python, tkinter

Consider the following code, which generates a (basic) GUI:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        button = tk.Button(root, text="I am a button")
        button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("This is a game window")     # I would like to move this code to the Game class
game = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The resulting GUI looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to achieve the same effect but move the setting of the window title to the class definition. (I've tried `self.root.title = "This is a game window"` in the `__init__` but this seemed to have no effect). Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. You need to call the `.title` method. Doing

```
root.title = "This is a game window"
```

doesn't set the title, it overwrites the method with the string.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("This is a game window")

        button = tk.Button(root, text="I am a button")
        button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
game = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

You *could* also do `self.root.title("This is a game window")` but it's more typing, and using `self.root` is slightly less efficient than using the  `root` parameter that was passed to the `__init__` method, since `self.root` requires an attribute lookup but `root` is a simple local variable.